# Given $L$ and $D$ find $X, \text { such that } X * 10^L + D \equiv 0 \mod M$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Given $L$ and $D$ find $X, \text { such that } X * 10^L + D \equiv 0 \mod M$. Integer $M$ is given and it is the same for all calculations however we need to solve for $X$ for more different numbers.  One important thing that we know is that $\gcd(M, 10) = 1$.

I rewrited the equation in this type:
$X * 10^L \equiv M - D \mod M$. If $M$ was prime number we could just multiply $M-D$ by $(10^L)^{M-2}$. However $M$ might be arbitrary integer. How can we use the fact that $\gcd(M, 10) = 1$

Comment: This is essentially a math question, perhaps more appropriate for [math.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $10$ is relatively prime to $M$, it has an inverse modulo $M$, which can be found efficiently using the extended GCD algorithm. So you can simply calculate $X = -10^{-L}D$ (all computations modulo $M$).